# call stored procedure oracle parameter array using scala / java

Tags: java, oracle, scala, playframework

i have this code :

procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_ARRAY AS   PROCEDURE PARAAJA_BULK(P_INPUTS IN PARAAJAARRAY) 
IS   BEGIN
        FOR I IN 1 .. P_INPUTS.COUNT LOOP

          INSERT INTO PARA_AJA
            (FIELD1, FIELD2)
          VALUES
            (P_INPUTS(I).FIELD1, P_INPUTS(I).FIELD2);
        END LOOP;   END;

    END;
```

and scala code :

```
def spArray(name: List[person2],con:Connection) = Future[Boolean] { //supaya output jadi Future

    DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver())
    val conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxx)(PORT=xxxx))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=xxxx)))", "tesschema", "1234")
    var callableStatement: CallableStatement = conn.prepareCall("call PKG_ARRAY.PARAAJA_BULK(?)")

    val des = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("PKG_ARRAY.PARAAJAARRAY", conn)
    val array_to_pass = new ARRAY(des, conn, name)

    callableStatement.setArray(1, array_to_pass)
    callableStatement.execute()

  }
```

but ,i have problem !!

invalid name pattern: PKG_ARRAY.PARAAJAARRAY

...

Answer (score 1):

in java i used oracle procedure like:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = Connection.prepareCall("{CALL CmdtyStndrd.CmdtyStndrdProc(?)}");
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, array_to_pass);
cstmt.execute();
```

and it works.

Comment: Can also be done (more easily?) in Scala using [Anorm](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAnorm)

Answer (score 0):

PARAAJAARRAY should be a schema-level defined type, not a type defined at package level. Try to create the type with CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE PARAAJAARRAY as TABLE OF (your record object type).