# How to define a PL/SQL function and call it from another language

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to write a PL/SQL function that returns a number. I must use the number in SQL where clause. The function is in the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_id(str_id IN STRING,num_group IN NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  result NUMBER;
declare
  temp STRING;
BEGIN
  temp := substr(str_id, -least(length(str_id), 2));
  result := TO_NUMBER(temp) % num_group;
  RETURN result;
END;

select * from table where func_id("id",2)=1
```

**2** and **1** are just an example. I want to call the function in my Scala Program that variables are replaced in place of **2** and **1**.

When I run the code in SQL Developer I receive this error:

```
 Function FUNC_ID compiled

 LINE/COL  ERROR
 --------- -------------------------------------------------------------
 5/1       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    exists prior The symbol "begin" was substituted for "DECLARE" to continue. 
 13/54     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     . , @ ; for <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> group having intersect    minus order partition start subpartition union where connect    sample
```

Would you please guide me how to write a PL/SQL function and call it in another query or any where else?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: this function can work. str_id is a string, so the result of `substr(str_id, -least(length(str_id), 2))` is always a string, but the variable temp is declared as number. By the way, there are other errors in the code. Can you elaborate how this string should be converted in a number ?

Comment: If you tell me the logic for that, I can fix your code. So, if the parameter str_id is 'AAAA' , how this should be converte3d to a number ?

Comment: Dear @RobertoHernandez, thank you for your feedback. The data is like '123456', I must extract the last two character and divide it two a number then I use the result of the function in a simple query.

Comment: and the str_id is always ID ?

Comment: No it is just a simple column.

Comment: the answer from @MTO covers your scenario. I was not able to understand from your post that ID was a column.

Comment: Compiling a syntactically valid PL/SQL function and calling a user-defined PL/SQL function from Scala are two different things.

Comment: Out of interest, why `substr` but `TO_NUMBER`? Is that a Scala convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `DECLARE` is syntactically invalid in that position;
- `STRING` is not a valid data type, you want `VARCHAR2`;
- `%` is not a valid operator, you want the `MOD` function; and
- The intermediate variables are not required.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_id(
  str_id    IN VARCHAR2,
  num_group IN NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN MOD(TO_NUMBER(substr(str_id, -LEAST(2, LENGTH(str_id)))), num_group);
END;
/
```

Then, if you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id ) AS
SELECT '1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '24' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '10-05' FROM DUAL;
```

You can call the function using:

```sql
select id,
       func_id(id, 23)
from   table_name
```

Which outputs:

> | ID | FUNC_ID(ID,23) |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 |
> | 24 | 1 |
> | 10-05 | 5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5f2832445920656e1a661d8df52352ad)*

Comment: you have deducted that ID is a constant, not a variable string to pass into the function itself. I was not able to deduct that from the question.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez The OP passes it as a constant in their SQL statement; its been in the question from the second edit.

Comment: Dear @MT0 thank you for your answer. Would you please guide me if I can call the function in another program like Scala?Do I have to make an EXE file of the function to call it from other places?

Comment: @M_Gh You would need to ask someone who uses Scala how to call it (or read the documentation); that is a language I have never used.

Comment: @MT0, you are right. But, I think I must do extra works on the function in Oracle to make it executable in another language.

Comment: @M_Gh, you can call the function in Scala . The java driver will interpret it as a normal SQL statement. In your case your function returns a number in the form of a single column. It would be the same if you run `select sysdate from dual`, in this case `sysdate`is an in-build function

Comment: @RobertoHernandez, you are correct. But, my function is not an in-build function. I think to use it in Scala program, I have to convert it to an in-build function.

Comment: @M_Gh No, you do not (and you cannot convert it to a built-in function). Just use it as is.

Comment: @M_Gh , you can call the function, same as you can call a Producedure or a pakcage. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980683/call-stored-procedure-oracle-parameter-array-using-scala-java

Comment: @MTO actually `string` is valid as the compiler will treat it as a subtype of `varchar2`. It does need a length though. Also `to_number(temp) mod num_group` is available for those more familiar with the `%` mod syntax.